# openiscsi initiator shared ext3 disk

Tags: linux, iscsi, opensolaris, ext3

i have an iscsi target disk with only one ext3 partition on opensolaris using comstar

i also have two ubuntu instances with openiscsi initators that connect to that disk

both instances have this disk mounted (same disk is shared between instances)

when i write some data on instance1 on that disk i don't see any changes on that disk on instance2, maybe it's related to cache, if i remount the partition the changes are seen on instance2!

What might be the problem? Is it possible to use the same iscsi target disk shared between iscsi initiators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext3 isn't a cluster file system. You should not mount the same disk at two differents hosts whith ext3.

You can corrupt the file system.

Try use a cluster filesystem as GFS or OCFS.

Comment: thx, i've configured ocfs2 and it works perfectly

Comment: s/can corrupt/will corrupt/

Comment: if the iscsi filesystem is mounted RO on the initiators it works like a charm.

Comment: hmm intereseting, guess i'l switch to oracle asm , i needed that for oracle rac anyway